# Python - sum of integers in a list (recursive)

Tags: python, recursion, sum

I am trying to make a program that returns the sum of all integers in a list, bigger than n or equal to n. For example,

```
>>>floorSum([1,3,2,5,7,1,2,8], 4)
20
```

Here is the code I came up with:

```
def floorSum(l,n):
    if len(l)>0:
        if l[0]<n:
            floorSum(l[1:],n)
        else:
            s=l[0]+floorSum(l[1:],n)
    return s
```

I am getting: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment.`

Any ideas?

Comment: There are paths through your function that don't assign anything to `s`. In those cases, what `s` is the function supposed to return?

Comment: @khelwood is correct. Specifically, if `l[0] < n` then s isn't assigned a value. You need `s = floorSum(l[1:], n)` in that case.

Comment: @Oliver There isn't just that case. There is also the case when `len(l)` is zero.

Comment: @AsadSiddiqui The question has been up for less than half an hour.  Stop score grubbing.  Picking an answer too quickly discourages other answers and discussion.

Comment: @pjs  please go through all the answers, including the one posted by OP himself and you will know why I said that.

Comment: @sid-m I've done so, and regardless of whether yours was the best at the time or not, half an hour is early days to accept an answer on a site that is viewed from all around the world.  For instance, I just woke up and am browsing SO over my morning tea.

Comment: @pjs Alright, I get it.

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to initialize `s` to zero

```
def floorSum(l,n):
    s = 0
    if len(l) > 0:
        if l[0] < n:
            s = floorSum(l[1:], n)
        else:
            s = l[0] + floorSum(l[1:], n)
    else:
         return 0
    return s
```

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, you neglected to initialize `s` for all cases and check for a length of zero.

Here's an alternative approach:

```
def floorSum(l, n):
    if len(l) > 1:
        mid = len(l) // 2  # Python 3 integer division
        return floorSum(l[:mid], n) + floorSum(l[mid:], n)
    if len(l) == 1 and l[0] >= n:
        return l[0]
    return 0
```

This version will divide the list into halves at each step, so although it doesn't do any less work the depth of the recursion stack is O(log(len(l))) rather than O(len(l)).  That will prevent stack overflow for large lists.

Another benefit of this approach is the additional storage requirements.  Python is creating sublists in both versions, but in your original version the additional storage required for the sublists is `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1`, which is O(n<sup>2</sup>). With the successive halving approach, the additional storage requirement is O(n log n), which is substantially lower for large values of n. Allocating and freeing that additional storage may even impact the run time for large n.  (Note, however, that this can be avoided in both algorithms by passing the indices of the range of interest as arguments rather than creating sublists.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I solved the problem!

Forgot to put s=0

Answer (score -1):

Python is a wonderful language that allows you to do that in a single line with list comprehension.

```
s = sum([value for value in l if value >= n])
```

Another way is to use `filter`

```
s = sum(filter(lambda e: e >= n, l))
```

The first one basically says:

"Create a new list from the elements of `l`, so that they are all greater or equal to `n`. Sum that new list."

The second one:

"Filter only the elements that are greater or equal to `n`. Sum over that."

You can find ample documentation on both of these techniques.

If you found the answer useful, mark it as accepted

Comment: Since OP has a recursion tag and explicitly specified recursion in the subject line, this isn't an answer.